# How does execution of !find command work?

Tags: shell, command-history

The `!find` command lets the user perform the previously executed `find`, with all its parameters.

How does it work internally, where exactly has this behaviour been programmed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not related to the `find` command itself, it's a feature of the shell called history expansion. If your shell supports history expansion, you can refer to a past command you typed and do some things with it.

For example in Bash, your action refers to a command from history by an event designator. From the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html):

> An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the history list. Unless the reference is absolute, events are relative to the current position in the history list.
>
> `!`
>
> Start a history substitution, except when followed by a space, tab, the end of the line, `=` or `(` (when the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin).
>
> `!string`
>
> Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list starting with string.

For the real internals you can read the source code of [`get_history_event`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/histexpand.c?id=bash-4.3#n119) from Bash 4.3.